# Resolve Source map for proto-loader in VS Code

Tags: node.js, grpc, proto

When I run a node.js program, I get the following error:

```
Could not read source map for file:.../node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js.map
```

The inex.js file does exist, however there is no index.js.map file.

my launch.json looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--preserve-symlinks",
                "--preserve-symlinks-main"
            ],
        },
    ],
    "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "!**/node_modules/**"
      ],
}
```

How can I resolve this source map? Or can I ask vs code to skip index.js.map?

Answer (score 0):

change `"type": "node"` to `"type": "pwa-node"` in launch.json